# Debugging ERROR 999999 in Raster to Polygon Scripting?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-9.3, error-999999

I am trying to make a script which selects every .png file in a folder beginning with the letters "LG". I then want the scipt create a shapefile, replacing the "LG" with "SH", and then i want the script to buffer that shapefile and rename the buffer with the first 2 letters being "SB".

I keep getting an error 99999 error message at line 37!
( gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(INPUT_RASTER, Output_polygon_features, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE") )

I have posted this on stackoverflow.com but probably here is a better place as scripting for arcmap is probably quite specialised!

Can anyone offer me any advice to why this script doesnt work? I am running ArcMap 9.3.1. and (attempting) to run the script from pyscripter!

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RASTER2POLYGON.py
# Created on: Wed Dec 01 2010 12:20:48 PM
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: RASTER2POLYGON <INPUT_RASTER> <Output_polygon_features> <Raster_Buffer_shp>
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Conversion Tools.tbx")
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Analysis Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...

folder = "D:\\J04-0083\\IMAGEFILES"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder): # returms root, dirs, and files
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]
    try:
        first_2_letters = filename_zero[0] + filename_zero[1]
    except:
        first_2_letters = "XX"

    if first_2_letters == "LG":
        Output_polygon_features = "D:\\J04-0083\\ShapeFiles.gdb\\" + "SH_" + filename + ".shp"

        # Process: Raster to Polygon...

        INPUT_RASTER = os.path.join(root + "\\" + filename_zero + ".png")
        gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(INPUT_RASTER, Output_polygon_features, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE") 

        Distance__value_or_field_ = "5 Meters"
        Raster_Buffer_shp = "SB_" + filename + ".shp"

        # Process: Buffer...
        gp.Buffer_analysis(Output_polygon_features, Raster_Buffer_shp, Distance__value_or_field_, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "")
```

Comment: Does the conversion work when you try to do it manually?

Comment: Sadly yes! So the problem lies in the script! I made it initially in model builder and it ran fine, its just now i want to run it for multiple files is there a problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered you over on the ESRI Python Forum

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18825-Raster-to-polygon-script-loop-failing!!-error-99999!?p=60693#post60693

Full annotation and reworked script, but the essence of the problem was trying to name the feature class in the File Geodatabase with a .shp extension. And then not cleaning up after each script run.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I have a new error now! I have posted the details on the ESRI forum!

Comment: My fault, problem was with selection logic to isolate the image file to be used. Corrected over on the ESRI Python forum thread as linked above.

Answer (score 7):

Try changing

```
Output_polygon_features = "D:\\J04-0083\\ShapeFiles.gdb\\" + "SH_" + filename + ".shp"
```

to

```
Output_polygon_features = "D:\\J04-0083\\ShapeFiles\\" + "SH_" + filename + ".shp"
```

And rename your output directory accordingly.

I think ArcGIS is getting confused between creating a feature class called "SH_" + filename + ".shp" in a file geodatabase called *ShapeFiles*, and creating a shapefile in a folder called *ShapeFiles.gdb*

Caveat: this made the difference for me, but I have v10, and cannot test on 9.3

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest trying to print out the output at each step of your program. For example:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder): # returms root, dirs, and files
    for filename in filenames:
        print filename
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) 
        print filename_split
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]
        print filename_zero
```

An alternative could be to use, gp.AddMessage( filename ) etc, if you are running it from ArcGIS too.

Also, do you need '\' after "D:\J04-0083\IMAGEFILES" ?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here are a couple of things:

1. I don't think the indention level of
   the code you posted is correct. The
   variable `filename` is
   used outside its scope, for example.
2. Some uses of `os.path.join` in that code are pointless. The string fragments should be arguments: `os.path.join(root, filename_zero + ".png")`
3. It is a good practice to avoid using
   `try..except` in this
   manner. Here is an alternative syntax
   that should do the same thing but is more [Pythonic](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).

   ```
   for filename in filenames:
      name = path.splitext(filename)[0]
      prefix = name[0:2] or "XX"
   ```

Finally, use the `pdb` module to step through the code ([link](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#module-pdb)). Much easier to catch future input errors this way.